# modify 3rd party code and merge updates if necessary  - Git or SVN?

Tags: git, svn

Last several days I was trying to set up a proper local SVN (with svn:externals) to be able to:

- have  a local SVN repository (simple)
- Keep track of changes I make to the 3rd party code (simple)
- merge official updates (remote SVN repo) from time to time

With SVN, that can be done with svn:externals set to a separate brunch which is merged to trunk from time to time.

I must confess I still have problems to implement this strategy, but the question is:

**would it be simpler / preferable to implement with Git** ?
3rd party code has Git repo as well.
Since I set up a local CVS now, I can go with any (Git/SVN).

What would you recommend? And if doing it with git, what commands do I look at? I read somewhere that merging is easier with Git, so would it be a better solution for my needs?

I would be grateful for your advices.

p/s/ I'm on **Linux**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SVN, you cannot track changes you make to a third-party repository.  I know of no way to do that.  (Unless I'm mistaken, `svn:externals` doesn't do that.  The `svn:externals` feature just lets you choose a specific version from a third party repository, but you can't commit changes inside it without committing to the external repository.)

Git is designed to do *exactly that* — you create a fork, and merge changes from upstream.  In fact, Git behaves this way by default.  It requires no additional configuration.  If the main project is Git, you can use `git submodule` as a rough equivalent to `svn:externals`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to set up a local repository at all? Or I just `git clone path/to/3rd/party/repo myFolder`  and then do changes my changes there? And then from time to time do `git pull` ?

Comment: The purpose of the `git clone` command is to create a local repository, so there is no extra step.  You can `git pull` every once in a while, or you can `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (which is the same thing, but allows you to review the changes instead of blindly committing them).

Comment: just to be sure, I don't need to set up any branches to be merged later, right? I just `git clone` it, make my changes/add files/commit, and then do `git pull` or `git fetch + merge ` ?

Comment: Right.  If you clone a repository from an origin that has a `master` branch and no other branches, you'll get a repository with two branches automatically: `master` and `origin/master`.  The `origin/master` branch won't get cloned and you won't change it, it's a "remote branch".

Comment: just checked now that I have only 1 branch: `*master`  Should I add a remote branch (how?) then before modifying?

Comment: When you run `git branch`, it will only show local branches by default.  Run `git branch -a` to see all branches.

Comment: ok, thank you! Indeed shows two more: `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` and `remotes/origin/master`

Comment: "With SVN, you cannot track changes you make to a third-party repository" - **you** can't, I **can**

Comment: @LazyBadger: Can you explain, or are you just trying to be funny?

Comment: @DietrichEpp - I'll try. "Vendor Branches", i.e branch+svn:externals in own repo. Track and support own fork of

Comment: @LazyBadger: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but don't you lose the history of the external project with vendor branches?  You could just as easily achieve the same thing by diffing the external project and using the diffs to patch your tree, and you'd lose as much information either way.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - how I can lost history, in case of linking to repo without defining of PEG-revision?

Comment: @LazyBadger: I don't think you get a unified history with vendor branches.  It's not "lost" in the sense that it's erased, but in the sense that the tools only give you pieces of the history which you would have to piece together yourself.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - for me trunk of any "mainline" branch is full history

Comment: @LazyBadger: Do you get the whole trunk with commit messages, or just snapshots?  Without the full set of commit messages it's not "trunk", it's a snapshot.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - external tree in repo identical to local

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using it local, you could use the file-based SVN [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)... greets

Answer (score -1):

If you move to DVCS (where **merge is more smart**, yes) and try to use first DVCS, don't use Git, select Mercurial (with MQ or branches /anonymous or named/)